# ¿Por que tengo el error "IndexError: list index out of range" en este script de Python?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, indices

Tengo el siguiente script... Estoy seguro que hay formas mucho mejores de hacerlo pero estoy estudiando el problema con los "breves" conocimientos que tengo hasta ahora a ver si puedo resolverlo. Lo que me llama la atencion es que me da el error `IndexError: list index out of range` en esta parte del codigo `for x in range(10):`. Aclaro que estoy colocando 10 numeros en la lista `cuit`  a traves del `append`. Digo que me llama la atencion porque son 10 los elementos de la lista `cuit`  y 10 los elementos dentro de la lista `num`. En cambio cuando coloco `aux1=cuit[0]*num[x]` se cumple mi objetivo que es tomar el primer elemento dentro de la lista `cuit` y multiplicarlo por todos los elementos dentro de la lista `num` y asi sucesivamente uno por uno. Se que en realidad tendrian que ser 11 numeros en la variable `cuit`  pero estoy intentando primero resolverlo como si fueran 10 numeros para luego intentar buscar la manera de hacer que el ultimo elemento de la lista `cuit`  se multiplique por todos los indices de la lista `num` .

```
aux2=0
cuit=[]
num=[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
inuser= int(input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: "))
cuit.append(inuser)
for x in range(10):
    aux1= cuit[x]*num[x]
    aux2= aux1+aux2
```

Comment: "estoy colocando 10 numeros en la lista cuit a traves del append" no es cierto en el código que muestras, cuit es una lista con un solo elemento, siempre lo es, solo agregas un item (un entero) proveniente del input, por lo que en la segunda iteración cuit[1] no es un índice válido. Por otro lado aux1=cuit[0]*num[x] no multiplica cada item de num por todos los de cuit, multiplica el item 0 con el 0 de la otra, el 1 con el 1 y asi. Para que fuera cada uno con todos necesitas un ciclo anidado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la variable cuit no tiene los 10 números, al intentar llamar cuit[1] te marca error debido a que solo tienes un elemento en cuit.

Yo haría anidar la parte en donde se piden los 10 números del cuit dentro de la multiplicación,

```
aux2=0
cuit=[]
num=[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

for x in range(0,10):
    inuser= int(input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: "))
    cuit.append(inuser)
    aux1 = cuit[x]*num[x]
    aux2 = aux1+aux2  
    print(aux2)
```

o también dependiendo de lo que necesites haría un ciclo aparte del que tienes:

```
> aux2=0  cuit=[] num=[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
> 
> for x in range(0,10):
>     inuser= int(input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: "))
>     cuit.append(inuser)
> 
> for x in range(0,10):
>     aux1 = cuit[x]*num[x]
>     aux2 = aux1+aux2  
>     print(aux2)
```

Saludos!